# Siteore 8.0 Publish Option

Tags: sitecore, publish

I installed Sitecore 8.0.
When I publish the item, it doesn't have Republish option like screenshot.
When I click "Publish Site", it does't have republish option either, only smartpublish and incremental publish.

How can I make the option appear??

[image]

I used development tool see the markup and Republish option has "display: none".

[image]

**==== Update ====**

Interesting!!!!!!

"Can Publish Republish" item doesn't exist.
So, I manually added new item named "Can Publish Republish" which has "READ" right, then can see the "Republish" option. Huu~~~

[image]

Comment: Are you sure it's not some custom (js?) code? I have Sitecore 8 and I see Republish option

Comment: Hmmm that could be. I will look at and if it is, I will remove this post. thx!!!

Comment: I posted a blog all about this issue here - http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/08/25/sitecore-policies-and-how-to-show-or-hide-publish-options-for-users/

Comment: From what I checked in the code, if it was a policy access rights restriction, then there would be nothing in the source (Visible is set to  false on server side - nothing is rendered). But there is republish option just hidden by `display: none`. Or am I wrong here?

Comment: I decompiled the code a few months back and ultimately if the user didn't have read access to the Security Policy all the code did was apply a display:none to the HTML element (think it was a div). Perhaps in newer revisions they have updated from a display:none to Visible=False

Comment: "Can Publish Republish" item doesn't exist in Core DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are specific `Security Policies` you can grant users permission to use the the different publishing options.

Using the `Security Editor` and `Access Viewer` you will able to see which roles have `Read` access to the Items which control what publish options are viewable by the users. The Items are in the `Core` database and at the path  `/sitecore/system/Settings/Security/Policies`.

Depending on your configuration you may just be able to add the appropriate users to the builtin roles of `sitecore\Sitecore Client Publishing` or `sitecore\Sitecore Client Advanced Publishing`.

See the following blog for more details and a guide to making the changes - http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/08/25/sitecore-policies-and-how-to-show-or-hide-publish-options-for-users/